# Javafx setmember conflict with iframe jquery lib

Tags: javascript, jquery, javafx, conflict

I am trying to setmember in a page with iframe but for some reason it doesn't work except when i remove jquery lib in iframe and parent here is the java part:

```
 if (newState2 == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                  JSObject window2 = (JSObject)  webEngine.executeScript("window");

                  window2.setMember("mainw", new Mainwin());
}
```

and this how js look like in parent :

```
window.onload = function(){

$(function functionToLoadFile(){

    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false,
        complete: function() {

          setTimeout(functionToLoadFile, 5000);
        }
    });
$.getJSON("remcl.txt", function(data2) {

var remcl = data2;

if(remcl == "1"){
    mainw.remendw();
    $.getJSON("reclbk.php");
}

}, "txt");
 });
}
```

and parent has iframe and iframe has jquery lib in its doc head

Would appreciate even a hint on why this happening,

Thanks

Comment: One side note; having a document ready (`$(function functionToLoadFile(){})`) inside an onload event handler is fairly pointless.  If the page has loaded, then it's beyond the point that a document ready would fire.  It will still fire, but it doesn't protect you from anything.

Comment: Thanks for advice. i will fix that now but still the issue driving me crazy